# Update Custom attributes of a product through CSV import

Tags: product, attributes, import

I am programatically updating some attributes of products through CSV import in "Advanced Dataflow Profiles". Of which, i have found the code to update quantity i.e. inventory information of a product.

Now there are some custom attributes which i need to change similarly. All these are string kind of attributes. But in dont get that in which database tables their values are stored. Can anyone modify the _updateAttribute() function so that i can update custom product attributes similarly??

I am using the following code:

```
<?php
```

class Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Updateqty extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product
 {

```
public function saveRow( array $importData )
{   
   function _getConnection($type = 'core_read'){
   return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection($type);
}

function _getTableName($tableName)
{
   return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName($tableName);
}

function _getAttributeId($attribute_code = 'price')
{
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql = "SELECT attribute_id FROM " . _getTableName('eav_attribute') . " WHERE entity_type_id = ? AND attribute_code = ?";
    $entity_type_id = _getEntityTypeId();
    return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($entity_type_id, $attribute_code));
}

function _getEntityTypeId($entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')
{
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
$sql = "SELECT entity_type_id FROM " . _getTableName('eav_entity_type') . " WHERE entity_type_code = ?";
return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($entity_type_code));
}

function _checkIfSkuExists($sku)
{
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_no FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity') . " WHERE sku = ?";
    $count = $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($sku));
    if($count > 0)
    {
        return true;
        }
    else
    {
    return false;
        }
}

function _getIdFromSku($sku)
{
        $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql = "SELECT entity_id FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity') . " WHERE sku = ?";
    return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($sku));
}

function _updateStocks($sku,$newQty)
{

    $connection = _getConnection('core_write');
        $productId = _getIdFromSku($sku);
    $attributeId = _getAttributeId();

        $sql    = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('cataloginventory_stock_item') . " csi,
                   " . _getTableName('cataloginventory_stock_status') . " css
                   SET
                   csi.qty = ?,
                   csi.is_in_stock = ?,
                   css.qty = ?,
                   css.stock_status = ?
                   WHERE
                   csi.product_id = ?
                   AND csi.product_id = css.product_id";

   $isInStock      = $newQty > 0 ? 1 : 0;
       $stockStatus    = $newQty > 0 ? 1 : 0;
   $connection->query($sql, array($newQty, $isInStock, $newQty, $stockStatus, $productId));
}

function _updateAttribute($sku,$newattri)
{
$connection = _getConnection('core_write');
    $productId = _getIdFromSku($sku);
$attributeId = _getAttributeId();

$sql  = "UPDATE `catalog_product_flat_1` tbl
    SET
    tbl.materials_value = ?
    tbl."

}

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');
$message = '';
$count   = 1;

    if(_checkIfSkuExists($importData['sku']))
{
    try
    {
            _updateStocks($importData['sku'],$importData['qty']);
            $message .= $count . '> Success: Qty of Sku "' . $importData['sku'] . '" has been updated.';
    }

    catch(Exception $e)
    {
            $message .=  $count .'> Error: while Upating  Qty "' .$importData['qty'] . '" of Sku (' . $importData['sku'] . ') => '.$e->getMessage().'';
        }
    }

else
{
        $message .=  $count .'> Error: Product with Sku "' .$importData['sku']  . '" does\'t exist.';
    }
    $count++;
echo $message;
}
```

}

Comment: It isn't advised to write into these tables directly. I think your better of with a module like https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport in combination with https://github.com/ho-nl/Ho_Import

Comment: alright , I'll check those links... Thanl You

Answer (score 1):

this is not a proper way to create files in Core Folders Helly.

you can create a custom module in magento and override the required Model. and if you want to update custom attribute at import time then you can import data using script.

It's Humble request to you Don't Change any Core Files Of Magento. If you want to customized Core Files Then Magento Provide us local Folder in  Code Pool. you can just copy and paste that file and override the Functionality.

Comment: Thanks but I have kept this file in local code pool under : app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Adapter/Productimport.php. And not modified any core file!

Comment: :) Thats grate (y)